# Extract 'name' from array of objects on init method

Tags: php

I have the below code:

```
add_action('manage_recipe_posts_custom_column', function($column, $post_id) {
    switch ($column) {
        case 'authors':

            $test = Recipe::init($post_id);
            var_dump($test);
            break;
    }
}, 10, 3);
```

Which gives me an output of this array of objects:
[image]

How can I extract all the authors 'names' only into an echo?

Comment: Maybe paste a short readable text of the array.

Comment: You will have to do that by whatever method this Recipe class actually provides for that - because the property is private, you have no direct outside access to it. This class either needs to provide a generic getter method, or one to specifically request the content of that particular property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, access the *authors* property of the *Recipe* object. You're going to need an accessible method, as it's private. This is going to give you an array of *Profile* objects. Cycle that array and use an accessible method to get the *name* property, as it's private. Then do whatever you want with that information.

It should look something like this:

```
$recipe  = Recipe::init($post_id);
$authors = $recipe->getAuthors(); // This needs to be a method of the Recipe class.
foreach($authors as $author) {
    echo $author->getName(); // This needs to be a method of the Profile class.
    echo "\n";
}
```

Format accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @JValker, but this worked great! Would you be able to upvote my post?